# What is the difference between sending carbon copies of mail message to other users and sending mail to multiple users at the same time

Tags: bash, mailx, syntax

In Unix, the `-c` option in `mailx` command sends copy of message to other people and has the following syntax:

```
mailx -s "Subject" -c "jpm,sumit" charlie < message.txt
```

where `jpm` and `sumit` are people to whom the copies of the mail sent to `charlie`, are to be sent. Here the other users' name are enclosed in double quotes separated by commas.

But, if I want to send the a particular message to multiple users at the same time (the name of the users stored in a file, say), then, what should be the syntax for that?   Also, what is the difference between sending copies and sending same message to multiple users?   And what's the difference in their usage?

Comment: @muru Can anyone tell me how to add a newline in my question description? Adding $\\$ is not working.

Comment: Add an empty line between two lines to create a paragraph break. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @muru Thanks for the links, I have been searching for it for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

`-c` Sends carbon copy mail, this means you send a mail to the server and the server sends a mail to every recipient. Also, this mail will have the list of the recipients available to all the recipients, so this way when they use a "Reply All" feature in their mail client, they will carbon copy to all the original recipients. This carbon copy disclose of recipients can be a problem under certain privacy regulations, if the recipients do not know each other or aren't from the same company.

`-b` Also does carbon copy, but recipient list is hidden to the client as you send a mail to the server and the server sends one mail to every recipient w/o the list in carbon copy. So the client won't be able to "Reply all", they just can reply to you and most likely you'll get all the answers threaded to your original mail.

there's no syntax to send a different mail for each address in a file (afaik) but you can

```
for address in $(cat ./addressbook); do mailx -s "Subject" $address; done
```

This way you are sending `wc -l ./addressbook` mails to the server and the server sends that mail to the recipient. Doing this can, however,  bring you problems with the sending  quotas in the mail server, if it is a public one it might consider you a spammer. Also when the recipients answers you'll get the response asociated to the mail with their address, wich can be a mess but could be useful to know who didn't answered.

Comment: Just a point of clarity. I don't believe there is any "splitting" performed by the server unless mailing lists are used.  That is, the client must send the message to the server once for each recipient.